# How to filter custom object in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have a custom object which contains data as:

```
@interface Students : NSObject
{

}
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString   *ID;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString   *FirstName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString   *MiddleName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString   *LastN
```

I want to filter it according to the last name. For example:
I want an array which contains all the details of students having last name="Cena"

I tried this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToFilter = self.studentList;
NSString *nameformatString = @"LastName contains[c] a";
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:nameformatString];

[arrayToFilter filterUsingPredicate:namePredicate];
```

When I run my app I am getting this error and my app crashes:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[< Students 0x7fd25e102d20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key a.'
```

I am only able to get last name in array but I know this is wrong. How can I sort the custom object based on last name.

Code I am using to get lastName:

```
  names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [self.studentList count] ; i++)
{
    Students * studentsObj = (Students*)[self.studentList objectAtIndex:i];

    [names addObject:studentsObj.LastName];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the predicate to ,

```
NSString *textToMatch = @"a";
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"LastN CONTAINS[cd] %@", textToMatch];
```

then

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToFilter = self.studentList;
NSArray *filteredArray = [arrayToFilter filteredArrayUsingPredicate:namePredicate];
```

for getting last name only,

```
NSArray *lastNames = [filteredArray valueForKey:@"LastN"];
NSArray *sortedArray = [lastNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Or, in other words, the property is called `LastN` and not `LastName`.

Comment: In predicate the property name was spelled wrong. and using `valueForKey:@"LastN"` will return all last names in an array.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr now again this error is occurring ... after getting sorted array i am again applying same predicate the i am getting eror

Comment: @user5370850 Sorted array is of type `NSString` so the predicate should be `@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@"`